# How to run a Symfony command in Windows task scheduler?

Tags: symfony, command, scheduled-tasks

I created a [Symfony command](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/console.html) that I can now use in cmd. I like it to be run every 15 minutes in my Windows task schedular. I created the task and everything to make it run every 15 minutes, but it doesn't execute the command. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the answer I figured out what I was doing wrong. I belive it is still worth posting since I've seen more people trying to get the question, in general, working but without success.

I had to remove the `""` in the field `Parameters toevoegen` (dutch for "add parameters"). It now looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT:** To answer DavidG it's comment; You can get into this screen by pressing the Windows button and search for task schedular (or Windows Key + R -> taskschd.msc). Create a new folder with the name of your project or whatever. Press right mouse button on the folder and click "create task". If you then go to the actions tab you are where I am in the picture above.

The "Beginnen in" full path is: `C:\xampp\htdocs\testExample`, where testExample should just be your project directory name, not command or public directory, just the main directory with all of Symfony in it.

Comment: Can you share the article that you followed to create this window task from the scratch ?

Comment: Also what is the `Beginnen in` complete path ? Is is the path to the symfony command file ?

Comment: @DavidG See my edit.

Comment: @Alart Yes I was able to do it with `Start in` set to the project path.